# Is there any way to quickly find all the edges that are part of a cycle(back edges) in an undirected/directed graph?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

I've got a minimum spanning tree. I add an edge to it. Surely a cycle is formed. I need to find all the edges that are part of that cycle ie., all the back edges. How quickly can that be done? My solution-
For example if it's edge (1,4), add 4 to Adj(1) at all places and run dfs every time. Eg. if Adj(1) had 2,3,5, first add 4 before 2, run DFS. I'll get a back edge. Then add 4 between 2 and 3 and run dfs. I get the another back edge. Then between 3 and 5 and so on. Is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: It is called a **cycle** not a circle. just FYI

Comment: Oh! sorry that's a typo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a tree you have a single (simple) route between any pair of vertices. If you are adding an edge `(i,j)`, first find the route in the tree between i and j and then you will have your cycle - it consists of all the vertices in that route(and turns into a cycle once you add `(i,j)` as edge).

Comment: and I think a dfs will suffice for that.

Comment: Any type of search will do for finding the single path between a pair of vertices in a tree. BFS, DFS or any other correct search.

Comment: I created my adjacency list a different way and was looking at that the whole time. So this didn't just pop in my mind! This was easy man! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the strongly connected components of the graph, which can be found using [Tarjan's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) ([among others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component)).

Comment: I don't think strongly connected components will help here. The question is a bit cryptic but OP is simply looking to find the cycle formed by adding an edge to a tree(if I understand it correctly)

Comment: If there's a single cycle in the tree, the strongly connected component of the graph will be exactly that cycle.

Comment: It is hard to define the term strongly connected component for an undirected graph. What do you mean?

Comment: Ah rats, missed the "undirected" part of the title. The tree I had in my mind was one where each parent has a pointer to each of it's children.

Comment: Strongly connected components are defined only for directed graphs I think.